# Which letter am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, video-games

```
Soul       61.2392559 46.6729113
Thunder    41.0257551 28.9742227
Rainbow    41.6947766 44.7778411
Marsh      25.2913771 51.5345946 
Cascade    15.5297874 32.5621657 
Boulder    60.187195  24.9250693
```

> Follow the *path* in the correct order to solve this riddle.

**Which letter am I?**

Comment: Comma disapear :o Just a formating correction ?

Comment: I do get something, but that video-games tag is throwing me off

Comment: @Sid He's referencing different pokemon badges

Comment: @Sid yeah me too, i'm thinking about several video games, but not sure for all of them
Edit : ok PaigeMeinke thanks for this help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my attempt.

> The words reference popular Pokemon badges. Taking them [*in order*](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Gym_Badges), you get the final answer, "H".

Picture:(Excuse my beautiful paint skills)

> [image]

Comment: arf was about posting my answer, nicely find :)

Answer (score 3):

> Looks like an R when plotted as x vs y
>  
>  
>  [image]

Comment: Very creative :)